# How to synchronize files in load balanced instances?

Tags: linux, synchronization, load-balancing

One of the challenges that we face during deployments on multiple load balanced instances is – the risk of not deploying the latest code base to one or more load balanced instances.

Idea is to use only one instance for direct deployment and entrust sync up to a script that syncs up selected list of folders to the other load balanced instances.

Are there any tools that helps us in doing this synchronization in LINUX boxes?

Answer (score 0):

Check out rsync

Answer (score 0):

This is an old thread, but Unison http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/